# Parsing JSON after Alamofire

Tags: swift, swift3

Having difficulty parsing JSON feed:

```
{
device =     {
    DMExempt = false;
    MRISafetyStatus = "Labeling does not contain MRI Safety Information";
    brandName = "Genius 2";
    catalogNumber = 303000;
    companyName = "Covidien LP";
    contacts =         {
        customerContact =             {
            email = "covidien.udi@covidien.com";
            phone = "+1(508)261-8000";
            phoneExtension = "<null>";
        };
    };
    deviceCombinationProduct = false;
    deviceCommDistributionEndDate = "<null>";
    deviceCommDistributionStatus = "In Commercial Distribution";
    deviceCount = 1;
    deviceDescription = "Tympanic Thermometer and Base";
    deviceHCTP = false;
    deviceKit = false;
    devicePublishDate = "2016-09-24";
    deviceRecordStatus = Published;
    deviceSizes = "<null>";
    donationIdNumber = false;
    environmentalConditions =         {
        storageHandling =             (
                            {
                storageHandlingHigh =                     {
                    unit = "Percent (%) Relative Humidity";
                    value = 95;
                };
                storageHandlingLow =                     {
                    unit = "Percent (%) Relative Humidity";
                    value = 0;
                };
                storageHandlingSpecialConditionText = "<null>";
                storageHandlingType = "Storage Environment Humidity";
            },
                            {
                storageHandlingHigh =                     {
                    unit = "";
                    value = "";
                };
                storageHandlingLow =                     {
                    unit = "";
                    value = "";
                };
                storageHandlingSpecialConditionText = "Keep dry;AVOID DIRECT SUNLIGHT";
                storageHandlingType = "Special Storage Condition, Specify";
            },
                            {
                storageHandlingHigh =                     {
                    unit = "Degrees Fahrenheit";
                    value = 131;
                };
                storageHandlingLow =                     {
                    unit = "Degrees Fahrenheit";
                    value = "-13";
                };
                storageHandlingSpecialConditionText = "<null>";
                storageHandlingType = "Storage Environment Temperature";
            },
                            {
                storageHandlingHigh =                     {
                    unit = "Degrees Fahrenheit";
                    value = 91;
                };
                storageHandlingLow =                     {
                    unit = "Degrees Fahrenheit";
                    value = 61;
                };
                storageHandlingSpecialConditionText = "<null>";
                storageHandlingType = "Handling Environment Temperature";
            }
        );
    };
    expirationDate = false;
    gmdnTerms =         {
        gmdn =             {
            gmdnPTDefinition = "A hand-held, battery-powered, electronic instrument designed to measure a patient's body temperature. It may comprise an electronic unit with an attached probe or be a single unit (shaped like an ordinary hand-held capillary thermometer) that detects and converts the changes in temperature into variations of some electrical characteristic, e.g., resistance or voltage. These variations of the electrical characteristics are processed in the electronic circuits and in turn displayed, for a short period, as temperature readings. Thereafter the display will automatically turn off or go into standby mode. This is a reusable device.";

            gmdnPTName = "Intermittent electronic patient thermometer";
        };
    };
    identifiers =         {
        identifier =             (
                            {
                containsDINumber = 20884521099798;
                deviceId = 10884521099791;
                deviceIdIssuingAgency = GS1;
                deviceIdType = Package;
                pkgDiscontinueDate = "<null>";
                pkgQuantity = 12;
                pkgStatus = "In Commercial Distribution";
                pkgType = CASE;
            },
                            {
                containsDINumber = "<null>";
                deviceId = 20884521099798;
                deviceIdIssuingAgency = GS1;
                deviceIdType = Primary;
                pkgDiscontinueDate = "<null>";
                pkgQuantity = "<null>";
                pkgStatus = "<null>";
                pkgType = "<null>";
            }
        );
    };
    labeledContainsNRL = false;
    labeledNoNRL = false;
    lotBatch = true;
    manufacturingDate = false;
    otc = false;
    premarketExempt = false;
    productCodes =         {
        fdaProductCode =             {
            productCode = FLL;
            productCodeName = "Thermometer, electronic, clinical";
        };
    };
    rx = true;
    serialNumber = false;
    singleUse = false;
    sterilization =         {
        deviceSterile = false;
        methodTypes = "<null>";
        sterilizationPriorToUse = false;
    };
    versionModelNumber = 303000;
};
```

}

I need to pull out key elements like 'brandName', 'companyName', 'versionModelName', ect.. I am having difficulty finding the right syntax to pull the data elements from the JSON dictionary.

```
                        Alamofire.request(criteria).validate().responseJSON { responseJSON in
                            print(responseJSON.request)  // original URL request
                            print(responseJSON.response) // HTTP URL response
                            print(responseJSON.data)     // server data
                            print(responseJSON.result)   // result of response serialization

                            if((responseJSON.value) != nil) {
                                if let json = responseJSON.result.value as? [String:Any]{
                                    print(json)
                                    let dataArray = json["gudid"] as? [[String:Any]]
                                    print("JSON: \(dataArray)") // serialized json response

                                }


                            }

                        }
```

I am getting errors anytime I reference json["gudid"].

Any examples or suggestions?

Comment: What log did you show (print(json) or prinf (dataArray)? Also, could you clarify "I am getting errors anytime I reference json["gudid"]." ? What error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your json is malformed so you can't parse it.  Please test it here:
https://jsonlint.com/

EDIT:

I believe the reason it's malformed is you must replace all equal marks (=) with colon (:).  This is standard json format.

Comment: That is a good point @Martin Muldoon.  The actual feed from the server is different.  The json I posted is from the Xcode output window.  The actual data is viewable from: [link](https://accessgudid.nlm.nih.gov/api/v1/devices/lookup.json?di=20884521099798)

Comment: Your message is malformed JLanders :-)  the actual feed from the server is?

Comment: I edited the above message showing how it is coming into Xcode and displaying with a print()

Comment: It will print it, but it's still malformed.  Print doesn't test for a proper json format.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon My guess is that's a print of a dictionary, not JSON, so there is no issue there.

Comment: JSON is based on Dictionaries, typically an array of dictionaries:  [String:Any] , you don't have json or a dictionary.  No equal signs should be in either.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon I don't use Alamofire, but if you do `(print(\(anySwiftDict as NSDictionary))`, you'll get a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

@MartinMuldoon was correct in that trying to look at the response with :

```
let json = responseJSON.result.value as? [String:Any]
```

was making the data unrecognizable for some reason. I am sure it is just my pure lack of skill.  After working with it for a while I discovered that if I modify the data like this:

```
let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

Then Serialize it with:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
```

I could then pull the elements correctly.  I am sure that there is a better way to accomplish this, but here is the code that worked for me.

```
               Alamofire.request(criteria, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
                                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                                print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
                                print(response.data)     // server data
                                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization


                               // let json         = JSON(response.result.value!)

                                if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                                    print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string


                                    do {
                                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
                                        print(json)
                                        if let gudid = json["gudid"] as? [String:Any] {
                                            print(gudid)
                                            let device = gudid["device"] as? [String:Any]
                                            print(device)
                                            self.inventoryDeviceVal.newModelName            = device?["brandName"] as? String
                                            self.inventoryDeviceVal.newModelManufacturer    = device?["companyName"] as? String
                                            self.inventoryDeviceVal.newModelNumber          = device?["catalogNumber"] as? String

                                        }
                                    } catch let error as NSError {
                                        print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    }


                                }
                            }
```

Hope this helps and if someone has a better method, please share.

Comment: What version of Alamofire do you use? Because it seems that it's converting JSON into `NSDictionary/NSArray` (Objective-C/FoundationTypes) instead of `Dictionary/Array` (Swift Types).